# backticks inside brace expansion

Tags: bash, command-substitution, brace-expansion

I'm trying to list the files of httpd processes, and I tried this:

```
ls -l /proc/{`pidof httpd | tr ' ' ','`}/
ls: cannot access /proc/{{28493,28492,28491,28490,28489,28488,28487,28486,28483}}/: No such file or directory
```

But if I put the PID inside the brackets myself, it works:

```
ls -l /proc/{28493,28492,28491,28490,28489,28488,28487,28486,28483}/ | head -6
/proc/28483/:
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jan 30 11:18 attr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 30 11:18 autogroup
-r-------- 1 root root 0 Jan 30 11:18 auxv
```

I believe in the first case, the shell is considering the backtick output as a single argument, and is not expanding. So I'm wondering, is there a way of making it see as a list to be expanded? I know I could do this with a for loop, or in many other ways. I'm particularly interested in learning more about backticks and brace expansions, assuming it is possible to do it.

Comment: Please use `$(` `)` instead of backticks: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of evaluation in `bash` is such that brace expansion is done first, and command substitutions are not handled until later.

Here's the order in which things are done by `bash`:

1. brace expansion,
2. tilde expansion,
3. parameter and variable expansion,
4. command substitution,
5. arithmetic expansion,
6. word splitting,
7. pathname expansion.

Alternative solution:

```
for pid in $( pidof httpd ); do ls -l /proc/"$pid"; done
```

Comment: thanks, this was very useful way of saying it can't be done. ^_^ I feel stupid for not asking myself in which order bash resolves these things. :$